# Filled "o" character in unicode or imitated via CSS

Tags: html, css, unicode

I need to write this text in HTML:

[image: Now.]

I tried to use some unicode characters like [● Unicode Character 'BLACK CIRCLE' (U+25CF)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25CF/index.htm) or [⬤ Unicode Character 'BLACK LARGE CIRCLE' (U+2B24)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b24/index.htm) but they need some styling (i.e. the size is different than in `o`) and have problem displaying on some systems and fonts.

Can you suggest a better solution? It can be a wide-accepted unicode character or some CSS imitation (in that case it would be nice if HTML still contains `Now.` string for good indexing). Image is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to use CSS `border-radius` to create the solid "o" circle.

```css
span {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}
i {
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span>N<i>o</i>w.</span>
```

Comment: Very nice but can I depend width and size on font-size? I am using responsive design and the font size changes.

Comment: The best answer is test it out, although the font size doesn't really control the width, but as long as you use a web safe font, it shouldn't output much difference. If you use unicode special characters, you might get emoji issue on smartphones etc. There is another option of using svg, if you tag it in the question, someone may answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want filled O character and not an ugly circle, the only (and rather simple) way to archive this is to edit your font and create filled "O" character. Sounds rather frightening, but it is an easy task to accomplish.
You can make a new font or add your custom character to existing font. For font editor you can use FontForge, for example.

Here is an example on how I made it with Percolator-expert font:

https://github.com/jehy/Storyteller-Dots

P.S. If you want just a circle, using custom font is also better because you have out-of-box control over font size.

**Another solution** - use unicode characters, provided by many fonts:

◉ ○ ● □ ■ You can output it with the following code:

```
&#9673; &#9675; &#9679; &#9633; &#9632;
```